# how to get a multiple of summary " Consultations "

Tags: regex, google-apps-script, google-docs

I try to extract all the " Consultation " and the dates entered in the text document GoogleDocs
and recover them to place them in a log file

I use a regex : CONSULTATION .... \ / .. \ / ....  work fine

like this

https://regex101.com/r/oI5eG4/5

My Script

```
function findNotesContactAjoutText() {

  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var bodyElement = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
  var search = "An"
  var searchResult = bodyElement.findText(search);


                /////      Recherche du "Nom Prenom" sur l' Ordonnace      ////

  var regexp = /[^0-9]*/g ;// extrait la chaine de caractère avant la chaine numérique
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getText();
  var result = regexp.exec(doc);
  var regexp = /[^a-z\s-]+[A-Za-z\s-]+/g; // extrait les espaces devant et derriere Nom Prenom  Demande la Présence de XX Ans (caché en blanc dans l'ordo paramédical)

   var NomPrenom = regexp.exec(result);


//------getContactsWithBirthdays();

   var contacts = ContactsApp.getContactsByName(NomPrenom);
  //Logger.log("Before: " + contacts.length);

  for (var i = contacts.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (contacts[i].getDates(ContactsApp.Field.BIRTHDAY).length > 0) {
      Logger.log(contacts[i].getDates(ContactsApp.Field.BIRTHDAY)[0].getYear());
       var birthday = contacts[0].getDates(ContactsApp.Field.BIRTHDAY)[0];
       var day = (birthday.getDay());
       var month = (birthday.getMonth());
       var year = (birthday.getYear());
       var Notes = (contacts[0].getNotes());
       var regexp = /CONSULTATION+.{1,12}/g ;// extrait la 1 ERE CONSULTATION du Patient                          WORK FINE ONLY THE FIRST
       var regexp = /CONSULTATION.*?$/gm ;// extrait toutes les CONSULTATIONS du Patient                                   DO NOT WORK
       var Notes = regexp.exec(Notes);

    }


  while (searchResult !== null) {
    var thisElement = searchResult.getElement();
    var thisElementText = thisElement.asText();
    var matchString = thisElementText.getText().substring(searchResult.getStartOffset(), searchResult.getEndOffsetInclusive()+1);

    Logger.log(matchString);
       thisElementText.setText(age+" Ans "+ "\n" + Notes );   //Affiche Notes         //I WANT ALL CONTACT CONSULTATIONS 

// search for next match
    searchResult = bodyElement.findText(search, searchResult);
}
```

}

```
  DocumentApp.getUi().showSidebar(
      HtmlService
          .createHtmlOutput (Notes)
          .setTitle('Notes Patient')
          .setWidth(350 /* pixels */));
}
```

NOM PRENOM   12/09/1970 1840042088011   10/07/2014

ATCD : DIABETE 2011  6 ET 7

FAMILIAUX : FCV0

TABAC : 00

VACCINS : REVAXIS 2014

SURVEILLANCE :

PREVENTION : TEST

TRAITEMENT : ( STAGID  3 cp /j) + METFORMINE 850 3CP   #

**CONSULTATION C02/03/2015**

CEFPODOXIME   2 cp matin et soir pdt 5 jours 
PREDNISOLONE   20  2 cp le matin pdt 4 jours 
RHINOFLUIMUCIL   3 fois / j pdt 7 jours 
DAFALGAN 1G   1 cp 3 fois / j  3 boÃ®tes 
TERBINAFINE  1 cp / j

TTT

**CONSULTATION C01/10/2014**

CEFPODOXIME   2 cp matin et soir pdt 5 jours 
PREDNISOLONE   20  2 cp le matin pdt 4 jours 
RHINOFLUIMUCIL   3 fois / j pdt 7 jours 
DAFALGAN 1G   1 cp 3 fois / j  3 boÃ®tes

TTT

**CONSULTATION C21/05/2012**

CEFPODOXIME   2 cp matin et soir pdt 5 jours 
PREDNISOLONE   20  2 cp le matin pdt 4 jours 
RHINOFLUIMUCIL   3 fois / j pdt 7 jours 
DAFALGAN 1G   1 cp 3 fois / j  3 boÃ®tes

TTT

I want to obtain

**CONSULTATION C02/03/2015**
**CONSULTATION C01/10/2014**
**CONSULTATION C21/05/2012**

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please, take a moment to read upon [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), it will help you alot on getting answers.

Comment: Thanks Kriggs but you don't help me !

Comment: Well, you say it works fine, there's no question in your "question", there's too much unecessary info, no formatting, no code attempt (since I don't really get your question dunno if it's necessary), no expected result and no current result, if you don't put some effort in your question how can you expect us to put effort on the answer?

Comment: I only want to extract with the regex all "CONSULTATION xx/xx/xxxx" and put them in a googledocs

Comment: Why are you using PHP regex when this is tagged as google-apps-script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GAS/JS solution:

```
var log = '', reg = /(CONSULTATION C[\d\/]*)/g, nn, str = theWholeString;
while( nn = reg.exec(str ) ){ log += nn[0] + ' '; } Logger.log(log);
```

Comment: Thanks Kriggs ,i have reformulated my question .. I wish that's clear for you ::)

Comment: @LolowrLolo Actually you lost me, since my code yields me: `CONSULTATION C02/03/2015CONSULTATION C01/10/2014CONSULTATION C21/05/2012`.

Comment: It's piping all results into a single string instead of an array of matches into their own strings.

Comment: @kayleeFrye_onDeck And? It shows how to get the values, anyone who can program know how to turn the string concatenation into an Array push, the focus of the question is how to cycle trough all matched of CONSULTATION with date, which my script is doing just fine.

Comment: My point is that Kriggs's answer seems to work fine to me, and that with a slight change in formatting to the output, this should be the accepted answer.